# How do I calculate the damage modifier for Bloodshed Blade?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, damage

In the book *Bigby Presents Glory of the Giants*, Page 111 has the magic weapon **Bloodshed Blade** where it states the following:

> "You can add your constitution modifier (minimum +1) to the damage rolls made with this weapon."

Does this mean that the weapon damage becomes 1dX + [Modifier] + [Con Mod]?
Or does this weapon just allow for Constitution to be used in place of Dexterity/Strength?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

### Features that *replace* the modifier with another use the word “instead”.

For example, the Hexblade’s Hex Warrior feature is very unambiguous:

> When you attack with that weapon, you can use your Charisma modifier, **instead** of Strength or Dexterity, for the attack and damage rolls.

For a magic item, consider the Snicker-Snack:

> While attuned to Snicker-Snack, you have proficiency with greatswords, and you can use your Charisma modifier **instead** of your Strength modifier for attack and damage rolls made with the weapon.

The druid cantrip *shillelagh* reads:

> you can use your spellcasting ability **instead** of Strength for the attack and damage rolls of melee attacks using that weapon

All of these features make it abundantly clear that the original modifier used is replaced with a different one. The lack of language indicating replacement, such as the word *instead*, in the description of the Bloodshed Blade indicates that its damage is the usual damage plus your constitution modifier, 1dX + Mod + ConMod.